Reference attached file to an annotation on a specific page
I'm using pdf-lib library in NodeJS to attach some excel files and reference them in an annotation on a page. I want that when someone clicks on an annotation it will open a file that is in the attachments of the pdf. I'm having troubles to link between the annotation and the attached file. this is my code for attaching the file. I'll be happy if someone can help me with creating an annotation that will reference the file. ChatGPT and Cloude did not help.
    async #addAttachmentToPdf(bufferArray, fileName, attachmentProps) {
    try {
        return await this.pdfFile.attach(bufferArray, fileName, attachmentProps)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error in adding attachmentToPDF ${fileName}`);
    }
}

await this.#addAttachmentToPdf(fileArrayBuffer, fileName, { mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel", "description": file.filename, creationDate: new Date(), modificationDate: new Date() });

this is how I attach the file now I want to create an annotation the reference this.
this is my last attempt but this doesn't work.
async #addFileAnnotation(anno,subType,iconName,fileName,mimeType) {
    try {

        return {
            Type: 'Annot',
            Subtype: subType,
            Rect: [anno.left, anno.top, anno.left + 20, anno.top + 20],
            Contents: PDFString.of(anno.stickynoteText),
            Name: iconName,
            FS: anno.voiceCommentUrl? anno.voiceCommentUrl: fileName,
            C: [1,0,0]
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}

const fileAnnotation = this.pdfFile.context.obj(await this.#addFileAnnotation({top: heightToRender, left: left, stickynoteText: fileName, fileURL : fileName},'FileAttachment','FileAttachment',fileName));
 page.node.addAnnot(fileAnnotation);

thanks!

so what do you suggest? can I attach the file directly to the annotation? when I right click the annotation (not a link annotation but a FileAttachment annotation) it can't file the file. I need a way that a file can be downloaded when clicked on an annotation. it can be reference to the attachments or directly on the annotation itself. my client knows that he needs to use adobe reader to view the pdf and download attachments
